# Может ли дискорд бот при выводе ссылок в чат не выводить изображения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

В ходе написания бота возникла неприятная история: бот выводит новости со ссылками, но потом после них также выводит кликабельные изображения-ссылки к этим ссылкам.

И ребята на сервере испытывают определнный визуальный апокалипсис:

[image: Вывод новостей:]

[image: А потом картинки:]

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при прикладывании ссылок от бота в чате не выскакивали эти картинки?

Бот написан на discord.py, версия питона 3.7.4 (anaconda).

##UPD##:
Shap Po предложил сделать ссылки жирными, это помогло частично.

[image: помогло частично решение Shap Po]

Answer (score 2):

Делай просто просто вот так: <ссылка> и не будут вылезать ембеды

[image: пример]

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант перед и после ссылки ставить `*` или `**` чтобы сообщение писалось курсивом или жирным шрифтом соответственно, такие сообщения картинку не добавляют.
Пример: `*https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*`

Comment: Хорошая идея! Но проблема решилась частично: бот все еще выводит мини-картинки. Добавил новый скрин в UPD